# How to create an entity representing a shopping cart in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, typeorm

I have created a REST API using node and express. My CRUD operations are performed via SQL in combination with the node module "pg", which allows for interacting with a PostgreSQL database. Now, I am thinking about refactoring my code to make use of TypeORM.

I have created the following three tables:

orders:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    status  VARCHAR(8),
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

products:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name     VARCHAR(100),
    price    DECIMAL(4, 2),
    category VARCHAR(50)
);
```

order_products:

```
CREATE TABLE order_products
(
    id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_id   INTEGER REFERENCES orders (id),
    product_id INTEGER REFERENCES products (id),
    quantity   INTEGER
);
```

I am trying to create the entities, which represent these three tables. I tried to do this, but I am pretty sure something is off. Can you help me with this?

These are the entities I have created:

User:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;
}
```

Product:

```
@Entity('products')
export class Product extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @Column()
  category: string;
}
```

OrderProduct:

```
@Entity('order_products')
export class OrderProduct extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  quantity: number;

  @OneToOne(
    () => Order
  )
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'order_id'
  })
  order: Order;

  @OneToMany(
    () => Product,
    product => product.id
  )
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'product_id'
  })
  products: Product[];
}
```

I think the OrderProduct-entity is wrong: The OneToMany relationship will probably create a column "product_id" at the many-side of the relationship, which is the products-table. I want to have this column on my order_products table, however.